# Replace webapp2 usage for self.response.write in python script

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm fairly new to python and have started by creating a simple app on google app engine, but now I want to deploy it somewhere else.
(I know I can install webapp2 in a non-appengine python environment but would rather not at this point.)

How can I change the following python code so that it does the same thing but without webapp2?

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        self.response.write('<a href="index.html">Search</a>')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

I've tried the print command, urllib, redirects and even considered scripting a basic web server, but none of those work or seem like overkill.

I'm trying to have a very basic python controlled/created welcome page with a link that goes to my single-page website, index.html.

I'm currently using Cloud9 which runs an Apache web server which loads the index.html if the python script doesn't work. However I'd much prefer to have the python script work in this simple manner, before I begin converting the whole thing to a full-scale Flask or Django application.

Any help or tips much appreciated.

Comment: The GAE experiment was probably not the ideal choice if this was your plan all along, because a GAE app needs a GAE-compatible PaaS infrastructure (not just webapp2).  Now you need to follow a tutorial/example for what you wanted to build: flask/django on apache :)

Comment: just migrate to Flask will be not very much work.

Comment: This is an open ended question.  Unless you specify a specific framework other than webapp2 you will just get suggestions to use other frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) gave me what I needed via WSGI and it turned out to be fairly straightfoward:

```
SEARCH = """<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center; padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 50px; font-size: 1.75em;">
        <p>Welcome:</p><a href="index.html">Search</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
"""

def application(environ, start_response):
    if environ.get('PATH_INFO') == '/':
        status = '200 OK'
        content = SEARCH
    else:
        status = '404 NOT FOUND'
        content = 'Page not found.'
    response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html'), ('Content-Length', str(len(content)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    yield content.encode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to handle basic requests using only built in modules, you could look up BaseHTTPServer and related classes. Here is a simple example:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer

PORT_NUMBER = 8080

class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('<a href="index.html">Search</a>')
        return

try:
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    server.serve_forever()    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.socket.close()
```

Note that this will not serve static files by default but you should be able to add multiple handlers. Maybe look up:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html